# Get filename from user and convert the number into list

Tags: python-3.x

So far, I have this:

```
def main():
        bad_filename = True
        l =[]
        while bad_filename == True:
            try:
                filename = input("Enter the filename: ")
                fp = open(filename, "r")
                for f_line in fp:
                    a=(f_line)
                    b=(f_line.strip('\n'))
                    l.append(b)
                    print (l) 
                bad_filename = False
            except IOError:
                print("Error: The file was not found: ", filename)




main()
```

this is my program and when i print this what i get

```
['1,2,3,4,5']
['1,2,3,4,5', '6,7,8,9,0']
['1,2,3,4,5', '6,7,8,9,0', '1.10,2.20,3.30,0.10,0.30']
```

but instead i need to get

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[6,7,8,9,0.00]
[1.10,2.20,3.3.0,0.10,0.30]
```

Comment: You should provide an example of input file, so that we don't have to guess or derive how it is. Also, what's the purpose of `a` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line of the file is a series on numbers separated by commas, but to python they are just characters. You need one more conversion step to get your string into a list. First split on commas to create a list of strings each of which is a number. Then use what is called "list comprehension" (or a `for` loop) to convert each string into a number:

```
b = f_line.strip('\n').split(',')
c = [float(v) for v in b]
l.append(c)
```

If you really want to reset the list each time through the loop (your desired output shows only the last line) then instead of appending, just assign the numerical list to `l`:

```
b = f_line.strip('\n').split(',')
l = [float(v) for v in b]
```

List comprehension is a shorthand way of saying:

```
l = []
for v in b:
    l.append(float(v))
```

You don't need `a` or the extra parentheses around the assignment of `a` and `b`.

Comment: thank you but i am still getting the same list which contain all the number ['1,2,3,4,5']
['1,2,3,4,5', '6,7,8,9,0']
['1,2,3,4,5', '6,7,8,9,0', '1.10,2.20,3.30,0.10,0.30']

Comment: use the second code block: where you don't `append` to `l` but just assign it directly.

Comment: one last thing if you can tell me how can i get a max or min value out of that list,i need to find max of a row and min of a column, thank you

Comment: do you want the cumulative `max` of the whole file, or the max of each line? Just add `print(max(l))` if you want each max, or save a separate master list and find the max at the end. To save the master list, either use `extend()` or add the lists together with `+` rather than `append`. You can read about the differences online. Good luck.

Comment: i need to put that data in table and get a max value of a row and min value of a column,max value of [1,2,3,4] and min value of 3,8,3.30.

Comment: Why don't you work on that and post your code as another question if you get stuck. It was good that you showed what you had tried for this question.

Comment: Does that answer your initial question about the lists? If so, can you [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so it gets taken off the site's To Do list. Otherwise, comment above on what you still need.